# Emacs CEDET: Jumping to symbols

Tags: emacs, cedet

I have read Alex Ott's [fantastic guide to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html#sec11) for Emacs, and I think I know how to set up my EDE projects correctly.

However, when I try to jump to a **local** symbol (e.g. the `main()` function in C++) using the command `semantic-complete-jump-local (C-c , j)`, I get the error `[no match]` even though I am calling this command from within the .cpp file where the symbol is defined.

Also, when I try to jump with `semantic-complete-jump-global (C-c , J)` to a symbol with multiple definitions on different  files (e.g. multiple `main()` functions), CEDET complains with `[not unique]` but it does not give me a  way to choose which symbol I want to see. The only way to find the symbol I am interested in is to cycle through all the options with `<TAB>` buffer by buffer until I find the one I am interested in.  Is there a way to get a list of symbols from where I can choose ? Ideally, it would be great to get an autocomplete list similar to those that Emacs [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm) (formerly known as [Anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/Anything)) provides.

This is all with **Emacs 24.2.1** on Linux with **CEDET 1.1**.

Comment: which version of CEDET are you using?

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt, I have just updated the OP with the version information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had you tried to use `semantic-ia-fast-jump` command? It uses not only Semantic, but also other data sources, to calculate where to jump. I just tried it, and it correctly jumped to variable, that was declared in the parent class, 3 levels higher in hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Alex! `semantic-ia-fast-jump` works great, but it requires me to have point (the cursor) on the symbol whose definition I want to jump to. Instead, I would like to jump to symbols that I can type in the minibuffer (i.e. a mechanism to navigate through symbols defined in my project). It would be great to see a list of all possible symbols that I can browse through to select the one I want. Ideally this would be some type of incremental autocomplete list that is updated as you type and refine the name of the symbol (like what Emacs Helm does). Not sure if that is possible though.

Comment: I think, that it should be possible to write such function, although it will require some coding

Comment: Thanks Alex. In the mean time, what other mechanisms exist to navigate, jump or preview symbol definitions?